# Spool/Capture output of COPY command in postgres/Redshift in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, aws, postgresql, redshift

I have shell script which will insert data into Redshift/Postgres database using psql command and i am using > for capturing script output. It captures everything but not how many rows inserted. When i run manually script on screen i can see rows inserted but not when i append output to file.

Currently i am getting -

```
TRUNCATE TABLE and COMMIT TRANSACTION
COPY
```

Expected output-

```
TRUNCATE TABLE and COMMIT TRANSACTION
INFO:  Load into table 'tablename' completed, 568 record(s) loaded successfully.
COPY
```

Command for insert from my script -

```
psql -w -U uname -h dbhost db --port 1234 -c "COPY tablename FROM 's3://bucket1/tablename.json' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=' format as json 'auto';"
```

Comment: That message is probably going to `stderr` and not `stdout`. Try adding `2>&1` at the end of your command.

Comment: Thank you it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only redirecting `stdout`, but that message is being printed to `stderr`.

To solve this, redirect the output of `stderr` (`2`) to `stdout` (`1`) by appending `2>&1`.

```
psql -w -U uname -h dbhost db --port 1234 \
-c "COPY tablename FROM 's3://bucket1/tablename.json' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=' format as json 'auto';" \
 2>&1 > /path/to/log
```